# Как легко сортировать числа? (1 минутА, 2 минутЫ и т.д)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

У меня есть дискорд бот на python. Но при выдаче бана/мута пишет не правильно (например: 1 минуТ). Но таких примеров реально много и написать все в if 2 or 3 or 4 не очень... Как можно обучить бота понимать какое это число и правильно писать слово?

Comment: ну  примеров  там   не  так  то  и   много,  вот  смотри,   все числа  которые  заканчиваются цифрами 5 6 7 8 9 0 - окончание "т" - 28 минут 103847 минут 6 минут  итд,   числа  что  заканчиваются   на 2 3 4 - окончание "ы" - 2 минуты   94 минуты ,    ну   те   что  кончаются   на 1 - окончание "а" - 1 минута  1001 минута.   Исключения  составляют   только  числа   от  11 до 19 - там   всегда  окончание    "т" - 11 минут  87612 минут.   Ниче   тут   нема  сложного,   просто   отделяй  последние   две  цифры    и   смотри  по  ним.

Comment: ну     раз   целого  бота   пишешь    то   я   думаю   запрограммировать   этот  пустяк   сможешь,   ведь  теперь  у  тебя  есть   направление - в какую  сторону  мыслить

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответил бы в комментарии, но нет рейтинга. Никакого машинного обучения не надо. Классическая задача, гуглить "склонение существительных после числительных", "Генерация множественных числительных в согласовании с существительным" и т.д.

Answer (score 4):

```
def conv(n): 
    es = ['а', 'ы', '']
    n = n % 100
    if n>=11 and n<=19:
        s=es[2] 
    else:
        i = n % 10
        if i == 1:
            s = es[0] 
        elif i in [2,3,4]:
            s = es[1] 
        else:
            s = es[2] 
    return s 

for i in range(1,150):
    print('{} минут{}'.format(i, conv(i)))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
def decl(number: int, titles: list):
    cases = [ 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2 ]
    if 4 < number % 100 < 20:
        idx = 2
    elif number % 10 < 5:
        idx = cases[number % 10]
    else:
        idx = cases[5]

return titles[idx]
```

Вызов

```
decl(21, ['яблоко', 'яблока', 'яблок'])
```

Answer (score -1):

Можно использовать библиотеку [pymorphy2](https://pymorphy2.readthedocs.io/):

```py
import pymorphy2

MINUTE = 1

morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()
print(f'{MINUTE} {morph.parse("минута")[0].make_agree_with_number(MINUTE).word}')
```

Вывод:

```bash
1 минута
```